# why is php class not being loaded

Tags: php, oop

Im testing this thing where i'm trying to load a class and use it like this:

> $this->model->model_name->model_method();

This is what I've got:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Loader {

    public function model($model)
    {
        require_once("models/" . $model . ".php");
        return $this->model->$model = new $model;
    }
}

class A {

    public $load;
    public $model;
    public $text;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load = new Loader();
        $this->load->model('Test');
        $this->text = $this->model->Test->test_model();
    }

    public function get_text()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

}


$text = new A();
echo $text->get_text();

?>
```

Im getting a bunch of errors here:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\A.class.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\A.class.php on line 24
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function test_model() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\fw\A.class.php on line 24

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any tip!

P.S. not much in the loaded file:

```
<?php

class Test {

    public function test_model()
    {
        return 'testmodel';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Could paste the Test class

Comment: what happens if you do a var_dump($this->load->model('Test'));exit;

Comment: object(Test)#5 (0) { }

Comment: try using autoload function to load the class. Besides, `$this->model->$model = new $model;` in your loader class there is no attribute model

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code(UPDATED) if you want to avoid `$this->model = $this->load->model('Test')` in the constructor.

You can simply load the models by calling `$this->loadModel(MODEL)` function

```
 <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class Loader {
    private $models = null;
    public function model($model)
    {
        require_once("models/" . $model . ".php");
        if(is_null($this->models)){
            $this->models = new stdClass();
        }
        $this->models->$model =  new $model();
        return $this->models;
    }
}

class A{

    public $load;
    public $model;
    public $text;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load = new Loader();
        $this->loadModel('Test');
        $this->loadModel('Test2');
        $this->text = $this->model->Test2->test_model();
    }

    public function get_text()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }


    private function loadModel($class){

        $this->model =  $this->load->model($class);
    }

}


$text = new A();
echo $text->get_text();

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I can tell this solution works, however this is not for me. I specifically want to use models in this format: $this->model->model_name->method_name().

Comment: $this->model->method_name() won't do If I want to load multiple models.

Comment: yes this partially satisfies my needs, however i want to get rid of this line in constructor: $this->model = $this->load->model('Test'); ...... id like to load it by simply $this->load->model('test');

Comment: Please check the updated code. This avoids the `$this->model = $this->load->model('Test');` in the constructor.
You can now load the model by calling the function `loadModel`.

Answer (score 0):

In the A class' constructor you are not assigning the "loaded" model to anything and later you are trying to use the $model property which has nothing assigned to it.

Try this:

```
class A {

public $load;
public $model;
public $text;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->load = new Loader();
    $this->model = $this->load->model('Test');
    $this->text = $this->model->test_model();
}
```

(...)

Answer (score 0):

Problem may be that you have not defined Loader.model as object but treating it like it is.

```
 class Loader {
    public $model = new stdClass();

    public function model($model)
    {
        require_once("models/" . $model . ".php");
        return $this->model->$model = new $model();
    }
}
```

When you have your class like this you can use

```
$this->model->model_name->model_method();
```

Comment: Yeah this would work, but again I'd like to add ->model-> after $this. (so it becomes $this->model->model_name->model_method(). I know it's possible, but perhaps i'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: UPDATED, you  need to initialize $model -member

Comment: UPDATED AGAIN, try instantiating with stdClass

Comment: Basically it only works if I add this straight to class A constructor: public function __construct()
 {
  $this->load = new Loader();
  $this->load->model('Test');
  $this->text = $this->model->Test->test_model();
 }